# How can I remove the repeated "will be" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

How can I remove the repeated "will be" in this sentence?

> Jack Shepard will be the Project Manager and Harry Gold will be the Superintendent onsite. Nicole Sanders will be the office administrator for this project.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly normal to say:

> Jack Shepard will be the Project Manager, Harry Gold the Superintendent and Nicole Sanders the office administrator for this project.

Alternatively, you could use *respectively*:

> Jack Shepard, Harry Gold and Nicole Sanders will be, respectively, the Project Manager, Superintendent and the office administrator for this project.

Answer (score 0):

That's where lists work well ...

> Positions:
>
> - Project Manager: Jack Shepard
> - Superintendent (onsite): Harry Gold
> - Office Administrator: Nicole Sanders

Or, in sentence form:

> The positions will be: Project Manager - Jack Shepard; Superintendent
>   (onsite) - Harry Gold; Office Administrator - Nicole Sanders

Answer (score 0):

I like the others so far, but I'll throw my hat in the ring:

**The project's positions are going to include Jack Shepard as the Project Manager, Harry Gold as the Onsite Superintendent, and Nicole Sanders as Lead Administrator.**